# video file to .ogg

Tags: media, ogg-opus

Ok So I have raw video file and a audio track that I want to put in container, as far as I know .ogg is an [Container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) so I want to know if there is a way to put my media files in this Container format like I can do this with .MKV format with this [tool](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html#windows) 
 I do not want to encode this video I just want to place my media files in Container format and I want to try and use .ogg format for this task

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried **ogmtools**?

According to [bunkus.org](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) *MkVToolNix* is:

**"MKVToolNix is a set of tools to create, alter and inspect Matroska files under Linux, other Unices and Windows. They do for Matroska what the OGMtools do for the OGM format and then some."**

And [bunkus.org](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/ogmtools/) for *Ogmtools* says:

**These tools allow information about (ogminfo) or extraction from (ogmdemux) or creation of (ogmmerge) OGG media streams. Note that I'll use OGM for "OGG media streams".**

One tool into the Omgtools is [ogmmerge](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/ogmtools/ogmmerge.1.html) *(Merge multimedia streams into an OGG/OGM file)*

If you want to install omgtools in ubuntu just type:

```
sudo apt-get install ogmtools
```

More information about OGG in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) and [xiph.org](http://www.xiph.org/ogg/).

Hope this will be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Try using ffmpeg.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53
```

Once installation is complete, use the following template as your command in terminal. For example, if you download an mkv file and want to convert it to .ogg:

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/file.mkv /path/to/file.ogg
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but I know about that end that is   re encoding/converting what I want to is just place it in Container format like MKVToolNix allows me to do on .mkv format. I do not want to convert video because I will loos quality

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with avconv (or ffmpeg, the syntax is identical). From the command line:

```
avconv -i input_file -c copy output.ogg
```

This will copy all the streams, no re-encoding is done. Alternatively, if you have separate video & audio

```
avconv -i input_video -i input_audio -c copy output.ogg
```

I'm not sure if the ogg container can contain raw video, you might need to use mkv or avi. Also, there's no reason to use actually raw video or audio (if that's what you really have) for archiving purposes; there are lossless codecs, which will reduce your filesize without losing any quality.

```
avconv -i input_video -i input_audio -c:a flac -c:v huffyuv output.mkv
```

You can also use lossless h.264 with

```
avconv -i input_video -i input_audio -c:a flac -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast output.mkv
```

Or 'visually lossless' h.264 with

```
avconv -i input_video -i input_audio -c:a flac -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset ultrafast output.mkv
```

The x264 presets are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower and veryslow; the slower presets give smaller filesizes, at the expense of longer encoding time.